# tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property not working

Tags: tomcat, java-11, embedded-tomcat-7

We have been using tomcat property tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip. It works all fine with java8 but fails to work with java11.

Using embedded tomcat.
Tomcat version - 7.0.91

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of tomcat generally do not work great with the latest and greatest java versions.  Have you tried upgrading to tomcat 8 or 9?  Tomcat 8 was declared stable in 2014 and 9 in 2018.